# LTO-5 systems compatible with Mac OS X Server

Tags: mac, tape, backup

I am looking to implement an LTO-5 tape backup system on a currently shipping Mac OS X Server (10.6.7) tower (PCI Express Card compatible). 
This backup system would be used only to offload data for long term storage to free up space for current data.

I am new to this so I am not certain whether native support for LTO-5 storage systems exists in Mac OS X Server and whether I need to look into any software in addition to basic filesystem support.

Any insights and links to resources are welcome. Excuse me for the basic nature of this post - I am at the point in my research when I don't even know what the search terms that will bring up relevant results are...

Comment: Not sure if off-topic. We've had meta discussions about shopping questions looking for rare components but I'm not sure what the final result was. Still +1 for mentioning tape drives.

Comment: I would expect http://serverfault.com to have more LTO users as tapes become economical when storing vast amounts of offline data and perhaps http://apple.stackexchange.com more users familiar with Mac Pro drivers and software for SAS storage. Your software / manpower costs are likely to exceed the $2k to $5k you'll spend on the hardware.

Comment: maybe you could explain why you want to do this on a Mac? Extending your scope to include other OS would make this much more mainstream...

Answer (score 1):

Most new tape drives especially after LTO-4 usually have a SAS interface. Most vendors like HP, IBM, Dell have LTO-5 drives available now. All you would need is to have a SAS PCI express card so that you can connect the tape drive to the server.

http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Highpoint%20Technologies/RRAID4311/

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/657316-REG/LaCie_131016_ATTO_ExpressSAS_R380_PCI.html